Windows 64-bit NASM - Why does this code not print anything, when using a variable?
Hello I have the following code:
extern GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA, ExitProcess

section .text

_main:
    mov rcx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle

    mov rcx, rax    ; hConsoleOutput
    mov rdx, msg    ; *lpBuffer
    mov r8, len     ; nNumberOfCharsToWrite
    ;mov r9, 0      ; lpNumberOfCharsWritten
    ;push 0         ; lpReserved
    call WriteConsoleA

    mov rcx, 0
    call ExitProcess

section .data

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE: dq -11

msg:
    db "Hello World!", 0x0A
    len equ $-msg

It compiles and links correctly, however nothing prints out.
If I replace mov rcx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE with  mov rcx, -11 then it work correctly, but I am not sure how to get it so I can use it as a variable.
Also if I change it to: mov rcx, [STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE]
Then the error changes to:
main.obj:main.asm:(.text+0x4): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32 against '.data'
I am budling the code like so: nasm -fwin64 main.asm ld -LC:/Windows/System32 -lkernel32 -o main.exe main.obj

Use mov rcx, [rel STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE] or stick a default rel at  the top of your file.

You are not following the Windows x86-64 calling convention correctly

@RaymondChen Can you expand upon that? Or what am I doing incorrectly? The commented out portion?

Stack not aligned on a 16 byte boundary, no home space for outbound calls, not enough parameters passed to WriteConsole, no unwind codes.

Or better, mov ecx, -11 (or make STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE an equ define).  There's no reason to put a -11 in .data when you could just use it as an immediate.  Raymond's correct about the calling convention, though: you need to pass a 0 at RSP+32, the first stack arg (above the callee's home space aka shadow space).  You're calling ExitProcess instead of returning so it's sort of ok that you don't reserve more space, you can let it step on your function's return address as part of its shadow space, and it might happen to work with the stack misaligned.  But better to learn to do it right.

How To Properly call 64 Bit Windows API In Assembly shows working code.  Also Hello World using NASM (and GoLink) on x64 64 bit Windows has similar code with some description of what's simplified (e.g. stack unwind metadata, which everybody leaves out of asm examples, and probably a lot of real-world hand-written asm, much to Raymond's chagrin.)

but I am not sure how to get it so I can use it as a variable. - What?  You want a runtime variable value to request different standard handles depending on how you ran the program?  Or do you actually just want a named constant, like STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11?
